# MS SQL Server Login successfull sometime Working But sometime not working

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql, sql-server-2022

I'm using pymssql to connect to MS SQL Server Database Instance. But Don't know why It's acting strange sometime I'm able to login and execute query and sometime It won't login. Tried to debug below code but honestly I don't have enough knowledge with MS SQL Server. Below TDSDUMP is given.

```
log.c:187:Starting log file for FreeTDS 1.3.13
        on 2023-04-11 15:58:00 with debug flags 0x4fff.
dblib.c:1187:tdsdbopen(0x55d76eff5b60, ***.***.***.***:1433, [microsoft])
dblib.c:1213:tdsdbopen: dbproc->dbopts = 0x55d76f0036f0
dblib.c:1224:tdsdbopen: tds_set_server(0x55d76efa5330, "***.***.***.***:1433")
dblib.c:251:dblib_get_tds_ctx(void)
dblib.c:1241:tdsdbopen: About to call tds_read_config_info...
config.c:170:Getting connection information for [***.***.***.***:1433].
config.c:174:Attempting to read conf files.
config.c:362:... $FREETDSCONF not set.  Trying $FREETDS/etc.
config.c:375:... $FREETDS not set.  Trying $HOME.
config.c:301:Could not open '/home/jibon/.freetds.conf' ((.freetds.conf)).
config.c:301:Could not open '/usr/local/etc/freetds.conf' ((default)).
config.c:362:... $FREETDSCONF not set.  Trying $FREETDS/etc.
config.c:375:... $FREETDS not set.  Trying $HOME.
config.c:301:Could not open '/home/jibon/.freetds.conf' ((.freetds.conf)).
config.c:301:Could not open '/usr/local/etc/freetds.conf' ((default)).
config.c:833:Setting 'dump_file' to 'stdout' from $TDSDUMP.
config.c:724:tds_config_login: client_charset is UTF-8.
config.c:733:tds_config_login: database_name is BlueChipDB_New.
config.c:833:Setting 'dump_file' to 'stdout' from $TDSDUMP.
dblib.c:1268:tdsdbopen: Calling tds_connect_and_login(0x55d76ef2f690, 0x55d76ef89880)
iconv.c:367:tds_iconv_open(0x55d76efa0440, UTF-8)
iconv.c:198:local name for ISO-8859-1 is ISO-8859-1
iconv.c:198:local name for UTF-8 is UTF-8
iconv.c:198:local name for UCS-2LE is UCS-2LE
iconv.c:198:local name for UCS-2BE is UCS-2BE
iconv.c:389:setting up conversions for client charset "UTF-8"
iconv.c:391:preparing iconv for "UTF-8" <-> "UCS-2LE" conversion
iconv.c:430:tds_iconv_open: done
net.c:391:Connecting with protocol version 7.4
net.c:318:Connecting to ***.***.***.*** port 1433
net.c:340:tds_setup_socket: connect(2) returned "Operation now in progress"
net.c:528:tds_open_socket() succeeded
packet.c:852:Sending packet
0000 12 01 00 3a 00 00 00 00-00 00 1a 00 06 01 00 20 |...:.... ....... |
0010 00 01 02 00 21 00 0c 03-00 2d 00 04 04 00 31 00 |....!... .-....1.|
0020 01 ff 09 00 00 00 00 00-00 4d 53 53 51 4c 53 65 |........ .MSSQLSe|
0030 72 76 65 72 00 c8 6e 00-00 00                   |rver..n. ..|

packet.c:410:Received packet
0000 04 01 00 2b 00 00 01 00-00 00 1a 00 06 01 00 20 |...+.... ....... |
0010 00 01 02 00 21 00 01 03-00 22 00 00 04 00 22 00 |....!... ."....".|
0020 01 ff 10 00 03 e8 00 00-00 00 00                |........ ...|

login.c:1342:detected crypt flag 0
tls.c:1023:setting default openssl cipher to:HIGH:!SSLv2:!aNULL:-DH
tls.c:147:in tds_push_func_login
tls.c:117:in tds_pull_func_login
packet.c:852:Sending packet
==Deleted== 
packet.c:410:Received packet
==DELETED==

tls.c:117:in tds_pull_func_login
tls.c:147:in tds_push_func_login
tls.c:117:in tds_pull_func_login
packet.c:852:Sending packet
==DELETED==

packet.c:410:Received packet
==DELETED==

tls.c:117:in tds_pull_func_login
tls.c:117:in tds_pull_func_login
tls.c:117:in tds_pull_func_login
tls.c:1059:handshake succeeded!!
login.c:1053:quietly sending TDS 7+ login packet
token.c:418:tds_process_login_tokens()
packet.c:410:Received packet
==DELETED==

token.c:422:looking for login token, got  aa(ERROR)
token.c:131:tds_process_default_tokens() marker is aa(ERROR)
mem.c:656:tds_free_all_results()
token.c:2402:tds_process_info() reading message 18456 from server
token.c:2497:tds_process_info() calling client msg handler
token.c:2514:tds_process_info() returning TDS_SUCCESS
token.c:422:looking for login token, got  fd(DONE)
token.c:131:tds_process_default_tokens() marker is fd(DONE)
token.c:2100:tds_process_end: more_results = 0
                was_cancelled = 0
                error = 1
                done_count_valid = 0
token.c:2119:                rows_affected = 0
token.c:2122:tds_process_end() state set to TDS_IDLE
token.c:445:tds_process_login_tokens() returning TDS_FAIL
login.c:599:login packet accepted
query.c:3757:tds_disconnect() 
util.c:179:Changed query state from IDLE to DEAD
util.c:333:tdserror(0x7ffdf51341b0, 0x55d76ef2f690, 20002, 0)
util.c:363:tdserror: client library returned TDS_INT_CANCEL(2)
util.c:386:tdserror: returning TDS_INT_CANCEL(2)
dbutil.c:75:_dblib_handle_info_message(0x55d76ef76380, 0x55d76ef2f690, 0x7ffdf51341e8)
dbutil.c:76:msgno 18456: "Login failed for user 'sa'."
dblib.c:8140:dbperror(0x55d76f003320, 20002, 0)
dblib.c:8208:dbperror: Calling dblib_err_handler with msgno = 20002; msg->msgtext = "Adaptive Server connection failed (***.***.***.***)"
dblib.c:8230:dbperror: dblib_err_handler for msgno = 20002; msg->msgtext = "Adaptive Server connection failed (***.***.***.***)" -- returns 2 (INT_CANCEL)
util.c:333:tdserror(0x55d76ef76380, 0x55d76ef2f690, 20002, 0)
dblib.c:8140:dbperror(0x55d76f003320, 20002, 0)
dblib.c:8208:dbperror: Calling dblib_err_handler with msgno = 20002; msg->msgtext = "Adaptive Server connection failed (***.***.***.***)"
dblib.c:8230:dbperror: dblib_err_handler for msgno = 20002; msg->msgtext = "Adaptive Server connection failed (***.***.***.***)" -- returns 2 (INT_CANCEL)
util.c:363:tdserror: client library returned TDS_INT_CANCEL(2)
util.c:386:tdserror: returning TDS_INT_CANCEL(2)
dblib.c:1277:tdsdbopen: tds_connect_and_login failed for "***.***.***.***"!
dblib.c:1491:dbclose(0x55d76f003320)
dblib.c:236:dblib_del_connection(0x7f79120dff00, 0x55d76ef2f690)
mem.c:656:tds_free_all_results()
dblib.c:278:dblib_release_tds_ctx(1)
dblib.c:6062:dbfreebuf(0x55d76f003320)
dblib.c:739:dbloginfree(0x55d76eff5b60)
```

I was expecting it to connect and return the query result. Sometime it's working but sometimes its giving below exception

```
pymssql.\_mssql.MSSQLDatabaseException: (18456, b"Login failed for user 'sa'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 14:\\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\\nDB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\\nAdaptive Server connection failed (***.***.***.***)\\nDB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\\nAdaptive Server connection failed (***.***.***.***)\\n")
```

Comment: Have you checked the SQL Server logs to get the *actual* authentication error? What was it?

Comment: You could check the actual error on sql server: `sp_readerrorlog`

Comment: @ThomA, I don't know how to do that but I guess now you have mentioned I will dig into it.

Comment: If you're using SSMS, then going to Management -> SQL Server Logs -> <relevant log file) in the object explorer would probably be the simpliest method. Then you can find the logs for the date and time you got the connection failure and get the authentication error.

Comment: can you compare tds dump between failed and successful connection? maybe the ssl settings differ or something like it?